# What bug is this? (England)

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I have found this small bug on the wall in my bedroom, and have been trying to figure it out what it is for months. 
There are more of this kind. They are tiny, I can't see how they look like with bear eyes. I can only see their proper shape by zooming in. I have seen them on my wall, in my drawer and on paper tissue. 
I live in England in a very humid, dumpy flat. 
I have also found bites or allergic spots on my body, but don't know if this bug causes it or something else.
Any idea what it is?

[image: bug]

Comment: This is a booklouse (order "Psocoptera"), and from the inflated hind femora likely a member of the family Liposcelidae; that family is common in domestic situations as a stored product pest, so while they may not be responsible for your skin condition, you'll still want to have them removed (look for other questions featuring domestic book- and barklice for suggestions on how to do that).